# React / Firebase actualizar página luego de hacer la validación del email

Tags: reactjs, firebase, validación, firebase-auth

Tengo este código:

Intenté con reload () y no funcionó, cuando el usuario se registra en mi página, esto muestra una vista con un error que indica "correo electrónico necesita verificación", bueno, ¿El modo único para ver la validación es actualizar con f5 la página? Necesito hacer clic en el enlace de verificación en el correo electrónico, esta página se actualiza

```
 useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (logFirebase) => {
      if (logFirebase) {
        setUsuarioGlobal(logFirebase);
        setUserMail(logFirebase.email);
        if (logFirebase && logFirebase.emailVerified === false) {
          sendEmailVerification(logFirebase).then(() => {
            alert(`Verifica tu casilla de correo, para validar tu identidad`);
          });
        }
        logFirebase.reload();
      } else {
        setUsuarioGlobal(null);
      }
    });
 }, []);
```

Este es el error de representación del código o muestra el contenido de la página:

```
return (
    usuarioGlobal.emailVerified ? (
    <div className="myAccountContainer">
      <h1>Bienvenida/o {userMail} !</h1>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <CTable color="warning" bordered borderColor="dark">
          <CTableHead align="middle" color="dark">
            <CTableRow>
              <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">ID</CTableHeaderCell>
              <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Fecha</CTableHeaderCell>
              <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Productos</CTableHeaderCell>
              <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Total</CTableHeaderCell>
            </CTableRow>
          </CTableHead>
          <CTableBody align="middle">
            {listaCompra
              ? listaCompra.map((compra) => {
                  return <MyOrders compra={compra} key={compra.id} />;
                })
              : null}
          </CTableBody>
        </CTable>
      )}
      <CButton size="lg" color="danger" onClick={()=>handleSignOut()}>
        Cerrar Sesion
      </CButton>
    </div>) : (<Error msg={'La pagina no puede ser mostrada ya que tu usuario no fue verificado!'}/>)
  );
};
```

Comment: Falta información y no está claro tu planteo, pero básicamente un componente se renderiza por 2 razones, cambio de estado o cambio de props, entonces podrías hacer algún useState en el componente q cambie en el lugar del reload. Es necesario q seas más claro en el planteo, cuales son tus componentes, código completo, el return es lo q mostrará, pero la magia ocurre afuera. Donde hace el registro, la validación y q quieres q se renderee tras la verificación, con sus respectivos códigos, de otra forma es muy difícil, eso explica por q nadie te ha contestado. Tambien tienes array de dependencias.